# Map domain name with tomcat application in windows 2000 server

Tags: java, tomcat

We have web application running in tomcat server in windows 2000 server. We are able to access the site using  `http://50.191.142.161:8081/xxx.`

And also, we have got the domain www.xxxx.com. Now how we can map this domain to that public IP without port no append.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do two things:

First youl'll have to map your tomcat to port 80.

There are at least three solutions:

1. Change the [HTTP-Port in your server.xml to 80](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)
2. Alternative you can activate the [AJP-connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html) and use [an apache-httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) as frontendserver
3. You can map the port with some firewall rules

I would use solution 1 or 2.

The second part is map your domain to the IP

I don't think you can do this by yourself, you will have to change the DNS-entry to your IP.

**update**

If you own a Windows Server and have a Domain-Controller installed, you may want to read this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11156